# Is TLS 1.2 supported in MySQL 5.7 community build

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

As a security best practice, I am exploring enforcing TLS 1.2 communication in MySQL 5.7.33 in my environment.

From what I searched in internet, I could see TLS 1.2 is supported in MySQL 5.7 builds which are based on openssl. Enterprise edition which is based on openssl supports TLS 1.2 and community build which is based on yassl does not support TLS 1.2 unless until we compile source code with openssl.

I am not getting a concrete answer. Is TLS 1.2 supported in MySQL 5.7 Community edition? If not, is there any work around?

Is there any blog that I can refer for implementation of TLS 1.2 . Please suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latest Version of MYsql 5.7.28 ad abouve suport tls 1.2

> MySQL supports encrypted connections using the TLSv1, TLSv1.1, and TLSv1.2 protocols, listed in order from less secure to more secure. The set of protocols actually permitted for connections is subject to multiple factors:

see [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/encrypted-connection-protocols-ciphers.html)

Comment: Thanks nbk . I have gone through the manual. Good starting point and some very good insights. Let me verify it my implementing it and share my feedback and also mark it as answer.